# Understanding why $a^2 - 2b^2 = 0$ has no solutions in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: proof-explanation, real-numbers

This is a minor piece to a proof that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ that I am trying to work out.

Given $x = a + b \sqrt{2} \neq 0$, I want to show that $x^{-1}$ exists. If $x \neq 0$, then $a$ and $b$ are not both $0$. The assertion that follows this is "therefore, $a^2 - 2b^2 \neq 0$ because the $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational."

I don't understand why this claim follows from the fact that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational. Checking the solution on wolframalpha, it seems that the general solution to $a^2 - 2b^2 = 0$ is
$$ 
b = \pm \frac{a}{\sqrt{2}},
$$
where I assume $a$ can be chosen freely. If that's the case, then $b$ is irrational. Otherwise, $a = b = 0$, which is not allowed here.

Is that the only reason irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ allows one to make this deduction? The only other argument I can think of it as follows. If $a^2 - 2b^2 = 0$ and $b \neq 0$, then I can rearrange and divide to get
$$ 
2 = \frac{a^2}{b^2} = \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2. 
$$
As $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $b \neq 0$, $\frac{a}{b} \in \mathbb{Q}$, and we've found a rational square root of $2$, which is a contradiction. If instead $a^2 - 2b^2 = 0$ and $a \neq 0$, then I can't find a similar construction. I'd rearrange to get $a^2 = 2b^2$ and divide to get $1 = 2 \frac{b^2}{a^2} = 2 \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^2$. Then $\frac{1}{2} = \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^2$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = \pm \frac{b}{a}$. While it is clear to me that I'm no longer in the rationals, this doesn't give me a clear contradiction.

Comment: "Is that the only reason...": I mean, yes.

Comment: @KentaS I was trying to understand if there is a more intuitive way to come to that conclusion than solving the equation, which I'm having trouble doing without assuming both $a$ and $b$ are nonzero.

Comment: I think about it as: $\sqrt2$ irrational $\iff$ $1,\sqrt 2$ are $\mathbb Q$-linearly independent, so $a^2-2b^2=(a-b\sqrt2)(a+b\sqrt 2)\ne0$.

Comment: $1/\sqrt{2}$ is also irrational